# Integrating C# web application with Survey Monkey API

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, surveymonkey

**I am trying to integrate my C# application with Survey monkey account . But I am not getting what exact type of App should be created in Survey Monkey.**

We have our web application where multiple Users can create then own account and use it. Those users would have their own survey monkey account with them.
When user will login in our application we want to connect his account in our system to his account in Survey Monkey. So on the basis of connected SM account we will provide the surveys to him.

Now the confusion is we are not getting what kind of App we have to create in Survey Monkey.

**Scenario 1** : If admin create one public app  named ‘ADMIN_SURVEY_APP’ in his survey monkey account , then Can I use the keys of ‘ADMIN_SURVEY_APP’ to get the access token for individual user account using Oauth2 authentication?

**Scenario 2** : Can we achieve Scenario 1 by creating Private app instead of Public app ?

**Scenario 3** : Or Is it require that each user has to create private/public app I  his survey monkey account to get access token ?

Please recommend what kind of flow we have to use to integrate survey monkey in our application.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an application that intended to be used by multiple SM accounts that you do not own, then you should be creating a public app, and authorizing the accounts via OAuth.

Private applications are for accessing your own SM account.

Is there a specific reason that you feel that you can't create a public app?